# React JS: rendering an image from blob

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render an image on my page by calling an API  from a `useEffect` hook. The service returns a blob, which gets saved in a state. Finally, the state variable is called from an image src attribute.

So far I have tried using the `URL.createObjectURL()` method in the image src's attribute, but I get the following error.

`<img src={URL.createObjectURL(blob)} alt="test image" />`

[image: error in console]

Also I tried converting the blob's string into a blob, then passing it into the `URL.createObjectURL()` method. The result is an image with an src attribute of `blob:https://i86fqf.csb.app/fcab2185-c1b2-4fe7-9c9b-8ca3c56a4467` but the image does not loads.

```
// Other imports ...
import response from "./response";

export default function App() {
  const [imageBlob, setImageBlob] = useState(response);
  const blob = new Blob([imageBlob.items[0].image.$content], {
    type: "image/jpeg"
  });
  const imageURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <img src={imageURL} alt="img" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: image not loading]

Any idea what I am missing?
You can find a code example here https://codesandbox.io/s/image-blob-not-loading-i86fqf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '$content' is the base64 string, and if you want to create blob from this, you can study the post here: [Creating a BLOB from a Base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

Or you can simply add "data:image/png;base64," to make base64 work as src.

```
  const base64 = `data:image/png;base64,${imageBlob.items[0].image.$content}`;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <img src={base64} alt="img" />
    </div>
  );
```